# Windows Phone 8 Emulator for Windows 8 Single Language

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Windows Phone 8 Emulator needs Windows 8 Pro edition or greater.

Can Windows Phone 8 Emulator runs on Windows 8 Single Language?Or do we need to upgrade Windows 8 Single language to Windows 8 Pro ?

Or is there any way to run Emulator on  Windows 8 Single Language

Answer (score 1):

64-bit of Windows 8 Pro edition is the requirement. You have to upgrade the Windows.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx